# How to stop early morning barking

Tags: dogs, behavior, vocalizations

I have 2 crated dogs who bark (or at least one of them barks early morning). I work shifts so get up at different times. I have tried ignoring the barking, ignoring the dogs for a period of time and it did improve but nothing seems to be working. I don't let them out until they are quite. They used to start when they heard any movement upstairs but now they start whenever. I have a 1 yr old baby who they are waking most mornings.

Comment: Well, there's https://www.google.com/search?q=bark%20collar, if other methods of training don't work out. Personally I'm not a big fan of them but I have seen them work.

Comment: Related: [Positive Reinforcement to diminish barking](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/positive-reinforcement-to-diminish-barking)

Comment: Doesn't this sort of barking usually mean "hey I need to go to the toilet"?

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, how do I access the original question???